Space of all solutions of a linear partial differential equation is linear
Peter Lax's Functional Analysis book Example 1.10 reads:
Example 10. $X=$ all solutions of a linear partial differential equation in a given domain.
Now $X$ is supposedly a linear space over a field $F=\{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\}$.
How I'd interpret this is:
$X$ is the set of all $u$ such that $$\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k}a_\alpha(x)D^{\alpha}u=f(x)$$ for given functions $a_\alpha \,(|\alpha|\leq k), f$, and where $k$ is the order of the PDE.
Now let $c\in F$, then for me it isn't clear that
$$\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k}a_\alpha(x)D^{\alpha}(cu)=f(x).$$Since this equals
$$c\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k}a_\alpha(x)D^{\alpha}u=cf(x)\neq f(x), \text{ if $c\neq 1$.}$$
So either I made a mistake in this last line, or I dont understand what is meant by the space of all solutions of a linear PDE. It might be the latter actually means the solutions of some linear PDE, but then I'd argue the wording is quite odd.
Coulde someone help me out?

The PDE must be homogeneous, i.e., $f=0$.

@Gonçalo Why is it implied that is required? Or is that needed for the statement to be true?

‘Now $X$ is supposedly a linear space …’ What suggests that to you?

@Aruralreader Well it doesn't say that exactly. This $X$ is just an example of a linear space, sorry for my own wording

Thanks @JackpotWizard180. It’s an affine, not a linear, space.

@Aruralreader Well, then why did Lax list it as a linear space?

Looks to me as if he said it’s a linear pde, but that’s my reading. Have a look at what a linear differential operator is all about.

@Aruralreader No, that's not it I'm afraid. He clearly lists 12 examples of linear spaces.

Why downvoted? ..

@JackpotWizard180: I agree the wording is odd.
